# How to pass information to modal?

Tags: angular, modal-dialog

So I have a table that I'm displaying with `*ngFor="let user of users; let i=index;"` What I want to do, is when I click on a button, modal that contains a form opens, so I can edit data. How can I send that index to modal? I'm using Angular 7 and Bootstrap 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a property for the index when element clicked.

component.html

```html
<button *ngFor="let user of users; let i = index;" (click)="idx = i">{{i}}</button>
...
<div class="modal-body">
  do somthing with {{idx}}
</div>
```

component.ts

```ts
idx: number
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a function that activates the form. Pass the index to that function as parameter.

```
<table>
<th>
...
</th>
<tr *ngFor="let user of users; let i=index;">
<td>
...
</td>
<td>
<button (click)="openForm(i)>Edit</button>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

In your Typescript code:

```
openForm(index: number): void {
//Display form here for the index
}
```